# How to extract top three values from 12 different columns and return the associated row name?

Tags: r, dataset

I am using a 43x12 data set that is built into R. The 43 rows are different people's names and the 12 columns are different stats. I need to get the people's names that scored in the top 3 for each stat. I can mostly do this except if two people have the exact same value for one stat I need to break the tie by using another stat, which I have no clue how to do. Also if they have the same value for a stat my current method doesn't work. The built in data set I'm using is `USJudgeRatings`. Here's how I was getting the top 3 for CONT, which works fine, but a similar method does not work for INTG as two people have the same stat which is the second highest for this category.

```
sortedCont <- sort(USJudgeRatings$CONT, decreasing = TRUE)
ContFilter1 <- USJudgeRatings$CONT == sortedCont[1]
ContFilter2 <- USJudgeRatings$CONT == sortedCont[2]
ContFilter3 <- USJudgeRatings$CONT == sortedCont[3]
BestJudges[1,1] <- rownames(USJudgeRatings[ContFilter1,])
BestJudges[1,2] <- rownames(USJudgeRatings[ContFilter2,])
BestJudges[1,3] <- rownames(USJudgeRatings[ContFilter3,])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `head` to get the top rows like :

```
row.names(head(USJudgeRatings[order(USJudgeRatings$CONT,decreasing =T),],3))
[1] "CALLAHAN,R.J." "LEVISTER,R.L." "WALL,R.A."
```

Then you can use `sapply` to apply it to each column :

```
sapply(USJudgeRatings, function(col) 
       row.names(head(USJudgeRatings[order(col,decreasing =T),],3)))

     CONT            INTG              DMNR            DILG           CFMG            DECI           PREP          
[1,] "CALLAHAN,R.J." "RUBINOW,J.E."    "RUBINOW,J.E."  "RUBINOW,J.E." "NARUK,H.J."    "NARUK,H.J."   "RUBINOW,J.E."
[2,] "LEVISTER,R.L." "CALLAHAN,R.J."   "CALLAHAN,R.J." "NARUK,H.J."   "DALY,J.J."     "RUBINOW,J.E." "NARUK,H.J."  
[3,] "WALL,R.A."     "O'SULLIVAN,T.J." "DALY,J.J."     "BERDON,R.I."  "CALLAHAN,R.J." "BERDON,R.I."  "BERDON,R.I." 
     FAMI           ORAL            WRIT           PHYS            RTEN           
[1,] "RUBINOW,J.E." "RUBINOW,J.E."  "RUBINOW,J.E." "CALLAHAN,R.J." "RUBINOW,J.E." 
[2,] "NARUK,H.J."   "NARUK,H.J."    "NARUK,H.J."   "NARUK,H.J."    "CALLAHAN,R.J."
[3,] "BERDON,R.I."  "CALLAHAN,R.J." "BERDON,R.I."  "RUBINOW,J.E."  "NARUK,H.J."
```

Comment: Do you have an idea on how I can break ties? For instance, Callahan and O'Sullivan have the same value for INTG. I would like to RTEN as the tie breaker, of which Callahan has a higher value. But how would I exactly go about doing this?

Comment: you can use several columns to `order` like `row.names(head(USJudgeRatings[order(USJudgeRatings$INTG,USJudgeRatings$RTEN,decreasing =T),],3))`

Comment: You are an absolute genius. Thank you!